# Missing variable FLTK_FLUID_EXECUTABLE

Tags: vtk, fltk, itk

While compiling **ITKSNAP** using **ITK,VTK and FLTK** on my computer(Windows 7 and Microsft visual studio 2012) shows following error:

CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.

Missing variable is:

```
FLTK_FLUID_EXECUTABLE
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:570 (ITK_DISABLE_FLTK_GENERATED_WARNINGS):
  Unknown CMake command "ITK_DISABLE_FLTK_GENERATED_WARNINGS".
```

I don't know how to link fluid executable.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Which version of ITKSNAP, CMake, ITK, VTK and FLTK are you using?  There are quite a few versions kicking about.

Comment: itk version 4.5.1, vtk 6.0 ,fltk 1.3.2. They all are latest vesrsion. Is there any chance ITKSNAP require lower end libraries?

Comment: Possible - if you look at http://www.itksnap.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Documentation.BuildingITK-SNAP that is what they test against.  What they're saying is that other combinations may work.